# Failed to run patroni

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, patroni

I have follow this tutorial: https://linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/create-a-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-and-haproxy/ , in order to set up Highly Available PostgreSQL Cluster Using Patroni and HAProxy.

But when I try to start patroni I get this error:

```
ubuntu@sudo patroni /etc/patroni.yml 
2018-05-31 09:49:37,159 INFO: Failed to import patroni.dcs.consul
2018-05-31 09:49:37,166 INFO: Selected new etcd server http://privateetcdIP:2379
2018-05-31 09:49:37,173 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am postgresqlm
2018-05-31 09:49:37,175 INFO: trying to bootstrap a new cluster
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
2018-05-31 09:49:37,185 INFO: removing initialize key after failed attempt to bootstrap the cluster
2018-05-31 09:49:37,673 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am postgresqlm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/patroni", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('patroni==1.4.4', 'console_scripts', 'patroni')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 176, in main
    return patroni_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 145, in patroni_main
    patroni.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 114, in run
    logger.info(self.ha.run_cycle())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1164, in run_cycle
    info = self._run_cycle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1077, in _run_cycle
    return self.post_bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 976, in post_bootstrap
    self.cancel_initialization()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 971, in cancel_initialization
    raise PatroniException('Failed to bootstrap cluster')
```

The configuration of `/etc/patroni.yml` is:

```
scope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: postgresqlm

restapi:
    listen: privateIPoffirstnode:8008
    connect_address: privateIPoffirstnode:8008

etcd:
    host: privateIPofetcd:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true
            max_connections: 100

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator privateIPoffirstnode/0 md5
    - host replication replicator privateIPofsecondnode/0 md5
    - host replication replicator privateIPofthirdnode/0 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: privateIPoffirstnode:5432
    connect_address: privateIPoffirstnode:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: rep-pass
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: '12345'
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

The configuration of `/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=postgres
Group=postgres

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml

KillMode=process

TimeoutSec=30

Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targ
```

etcd congiguration:

```
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://privateIPofetcd:2380"

ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379,http://privateIPofetcd:2379"

ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://privateIPofetcd:2380"

ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="etcd0=http://privateIPofetcd:2380,"

ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://privateIPofetcd:2379"

ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="cluster1"

ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
```

Of course, I have the real ips in privateIPoffirstnode, privateIPofsecondnode etc.

So, does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is obvious. If you start patroni with `sudo`, it will run as root, and that is exactly the error message you get.

Why don't you start it via `systemctl`? Your `/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service` has correctly configured a `User` that is not `root`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this. I have an another question too. With this configuration I will achieve load balancing in the term that the read requests would be distributed across the nodes in the system achieving a better performance? Or I need pgpool for this?

Comment: You'd need a load balancer like HAProxy. But since replication is by default asynchronous, the results will not be totally consistent.

Comment: Pgpool and ha proxy? Do you have a link besause I am completely lost.

Comment: Either or. I don't know if pgpool can detect node failure. [Here](http://www.haproxy.org/) is a link for HAProxy. Stackoverflow cannot provide a tutorial...

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse.

Comment: if I use sudo systemctl start patroni and then sudo systemctl status patroni i get :  Active: failed, Process: 11145 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) and the error says: patroni.exceptions.PatroniException: 'Can not find suitable configuration of distributed configuration store\nAvailable implementations: '. Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are missing environment variables for etcd.

Comment: I updated my question with etcd configuration. Did I miss something?

Comment: You probably missed adding that to the systemd configuration.

Comment: How can add them? I run on node with etcd : sudo systemctl restart etcd

Comment: Sorry, I cannot guide you through a complete Patroni setup. I think I answered your question. Look at the `systemd` documentation how to set environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://www.askvikram.com/how-to-set-up-a-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-and-haproxy) guide to configure highly available Postgresql cluster.

Its fully tested and working.